# iPhone 5 calendar

Tags: ios

**What does show all future user events mean in iPhone5 calendar?** I am not sure whether to choose

1. Choose only this event or
2. Choose all future events when I schedule a birthday

Answer (score 1):

This is displayed for **recurring calendar events**.  It looks like you're either trying to delete an event or edit an event.  The calendar needs to know if you want that change to affect a **single instance** of the event or **all instances** of the event in the future.  It depends on how the event was setup.

For example, when adding a new event you can choose how often you want the event to occur from the `Repeat` menu.

- **Every day**:   It occurs every day, at the same time.
- **Every week**:  It occurs at the same time, on the same day, every week.
- **Every month**: It occurs at the same time, on the same day, every month.
- **Every year**:  It occurs at the same time, on the same day, every year.
- **Custom**:  It occurs at the same time, on custom days. For example, you can set the event to occur on the first Wednesday of every month.